# I can't see the options in my drop down box on web page but can see it in element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have two dropdowns with the same options and I can't see the options on clicking the second dropdown, on the webpage, but I can see them in the element window. The first one is working fine but I don't know what's the issue with the second one. Also, the options are taken from a dynamic array. There is no error shown in the console thus I don't know what is wrong. I would really like someone to help me here.

I looked at other related questions asked on the platform but couldn't find a relevant answer, I tried deleting overflow: hidden but no luck.

```js
arr = ["Honda", "Suzuki", "Hyundai"];
var select = document.getElementById("Drop1");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
    txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
  option.appendChild(txt);
  option.setAttribute("value", arr[i]);
  select.insertBefore(option, select.lastChild);
}

var select1 = document.getElementById("Drop2");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var options = document.createElement("OPTIONS"),
    txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
  options.appendChild(txt);
  options.setAttribute("value", arr[i]);
  select1.insertBefore(options, select1.lastChild);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3">
  <select id="Drop1" class="mdb-select md-form colorful-select     dropdown-dark mx-2" multiple>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Car Features</option>
  </select>
  <label class="mdb-main-label">Car Features</label>
</div>

<div class="col-3">
  <select id="Drop2" class="mdb-select md-form colorful-select     dropdown-dark mx-2" multiple>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Bike Features</option>
  </select>
  <label class="mdb-main-label">Bike Features</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a type OPTIONS instead of OPTION in the 2nd loop.

Comment: You have  typo in `createElement("OPTIONS")`...get rid of the S

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo for:
`var options = document.createElement("OPTIONS")`
it should be
`var options = document.createElement("OPTION")`

```js
arr = ["Honda", "Suzuki", "Hyundai"];
var select = document.getElementById("Drop1");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
    txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
  option.appendChild(txt);
  option.setAttribute("value", arr[i]);
  select.insertBefore(option, select.lastChild);
}

var select1 = document.getElementById("Drop2");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var options = document.createElement("OPTION"),
    txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
  options.appendChild(txt);
  options.setAttribute("value", arr[i]);
  select1.insertBefore(options, select1.lastChild);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3">
  <select id="Drop1" class="mdb-select md-form colorful-select     dropdown-dark mx-2" multiple>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Car Features</option>
  </select>
  <label class="mdb-main-label">Car Features</label>
</div>

<div class="col-3">
  <select id="Drop2" class="mdb-select md-form colorful-select     dropdown-dark mx-2" multiple>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Bike Features</option>
  </select>
  <label class="mdb-main-label">Bike Features</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for helping me out here. I made the changes as per your suggestion but am still having the same issue. Is there anything else that I have to change or keep in mind that is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`<options>` is not HTML tag.

You did just a typing mistake, correct it:

```
var options = document.createElement("OPTION")
```